# How to iterate through a list<string> in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, timepicker

I need to get to an element in jquery or to use it as a value for a time picker min/max range, that is something like this `dealershipInfo.OpenCloseTime.ElementAt(i)`; where `i` will be an integer value.
& `OpenCloseTime` is a `List<string>`.

I am working in MVC. The objective is to provide a timepicker based on the min max values provided through the `OpenCloseTime` object.

What will be the best way to implement this?

Comment: What timepicker are you using? What does an `OpenCloseTime` object look like?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this with jQuery, but rather with code in your view.  The following assumes your model has OpenCloseTime as a `List<DateTime>` with the first being the start date and the second being the end date -- not sure why you wouldn't just map these onto individual properties on the model, but ...

```
@{
     var startTime = Model.OpenCloseTime.ElementAt(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
     var endTime = Model.OpenCloseTime.ElementAt(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $('#StartTime').datepicker({
             defaultDate: '@startTime'
         });
         $('#EndTime').datepicker({
             defaultDate: '@endTime'
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: @OBL - don't do it with jQuery, do it server-side in the view.